# Which universities teach true infinitesimal calculus?

Tags: teaching, nonstandard-analysis

My colleague and I are currently teaching "true infinitesimal calculus" (TIC), in the sense of calculus with infinitesimals, to a class of about 120 freshmen at our university, based on the book by Keisler https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html. Two of my colleagues in Belgium are similarly teaching TIC at two universities there. I am also aware of such teaching going on in France in the Strasbourg area, based on Edward Nelson's approach, though I don't have any details on that.

*Which schools, colleges, or universities teach true infinitesimal calculus?*

A colleague in Italy has told me about a conference a few months ago on using infinitesimals in teaching in Italian highschools. This NSA (nonstandard analysis) conference was apparently well attended (over 100 teachers showed up).

In Geneva, there are two highschools that have been teaching calculus using ultrasmall numbers for the past 10 years.

Anybody with more information about this (who to contact, what the current status of the proposal is, etc.) is hereby requested to provide such information here.

Note 1 in response to Dan's comment: usually nowadays the term *infinitesimal calculus* is used as a dead metaphor for "the calculus". Thus, calculus courses routinely go under the name "infinitesimal calculus" for historical reasons, whereas in point of fact no infinitesimal ever appears on the blackboard.  When I refer to "true infinitesimal calculus" I mean calculus with infinitesimals (as explained above) as opposed to ordinary "infinitesimal calculus" as found in Thomas-Finney and other textbooks.

Note 2 in response to Pietro's comment: I should clarify that calculus using infinitesimals is not limited to Keisler's book.  There are several books of this sort, including some that are unrelated to Robinson's theory, such as those by A. Kock and J. Bell.

Note 3: thanks to Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen for the update on the history of TIC teaching at the University of Hawaii.

Comment: This would be better at http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've voted to close as off-topic as this question belongs better at http://matheducators.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Willie, this question is similar to other questions under the "teaching" tag, and should be within the scope.

Comment: A version of this question was posted at MESE on Dec 8th: [link](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/5989/511). Comments but no answers.

Comment: @Joseph, the exposure here is much broader and therefore there is a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @katz: Yes, I understand. I was just notifying those who suggested it post on MESE that it already was posted there.

Comment: @Willie: the question now has a bounty, which prevents it from begin closed!

Comment: There is also a(n unanswered) version on [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057355/which-universities-teach-true-infinitesimal-calculus).

Comment: The obvious observation is: "Very few places do", so, definitely, it makes more sense to ask this question on the professional mathematician forum than on the general teaching forum (just to throw my weight to keep it open here). I would never do it in the undergraduate curriculum myself (unless the standard epsilon-delta language is taught in parallel) for the simple reason that very few texts in analysis are written in this language, so, alas, I don't know much as far as the main question is concerned.

Comment: @fedja, it wasn't my intention to discuss the relative merits of "epsilon-delta language" as you put it versus the infinitesimal method, but since you brought it up I would mention that we do teach epsilon-delta once the students have understood the basic concepts of the calculus like derivative and continuity via infinitesimals. Once they understand the concepts, they already know what the epsilon-delta definitions are trying to say, and it becomes much easier to absorb the intimidating alternating quantifiers. In fact I taught epsilon-delta last week, both continuity and uniform continuity.

Comment: @katz Neither was it my intention (the main purpose of my comment was to prevent this thread from being closed), so let us stop that side discussion here (though I would gladly talk about it somewhere else) :-).

Comment: @katz: the use of the word "true" suggests an implicit evaluation of relative merits. The question "Which schools, colleges, or universities teach calculus with infinitesimals?" - unadorned with the evaluative qualifier "true" - might receive a better response.

Comment: @Dan, I added a note to the question to explain the use of the term. This does not mean that the approach limited purely to epsilon-delta and an Archimedean continuum is "false"; rather, it means that it does not use true infinitesimals.

Comment: @katz: Vieri Benci tought calculus for freshmen based on Non Standard Analysis in the spirit of Keisler book for several years (I guess 15 or so) at the Engeneering Faculty, Pisa. You may like to hear him for a feed-back.

Comment: @PietroMajer, nice to hear from you.  Why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: @PietroMajer, since I see you are on the faculty at Pisa in Italy, could you comment on the recent interest in teaching calculus in highschool using infinitesimals? Are you familiar with Giorgio Goldoni's book?

Comment: Dear Katz, let me gather more information -I have no teaching experience about NSA, and no, I do not know Goldoni's book. I recall there has been  a meeting on NSA in Pisa, around 2000, which included teaching experiences of it at high-school level.

Comment: ( http://books.google.it/books/about/Nonstandard_methods_and_applications_in.html?id=cyzvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y )

Comment: @katz: Thanks for the clarification. Probably it is usually not a good practice to use "true" as part of mathematical terminology except in very particular contexts, for example expressly discussing the mathematical concept of truth. While one understands what is meant by "true infinitesimal", this terminology is not totally neutral. With a bit of effort one could surely find synonymous terminology less likely to provoke emotional reactions (perhaps "nonstandard analysis" was chosen partly with this sort of thinking in mind?) that only serve to confuse the discussion of the math.

Comment: perhaps "rigorous" or "axiomatic" would be better word than "true".

Comment: @Dima, the term "rigorous infinitesimal calculus" sounds precisely like epsilon-delta calculus, in other words the opposite of what is intended here.  Similarly, "axiomatic infinitesimal calculus" sounds like you axiomatize the real numbers instead of building them, and then again do epsilon-delta.

Comment: @DanFox, to respond to your comment about "non-standard analysis", I would like to share with you the reaction of philosopher Salanskis to the term "non-standard" from 1988: S'il a donc choisi d'emblée le nom d'analyse non standard pour le jeu qu'il définissait, c'est en référence à la notion de modèle non standard plutôt que pour suggérer le caractère divergent, subversif ou extravagant de ce jeu. De nombreux esprits, même les meilleurs, s'y sont pourtant trompés, de manière regrettable." What Salanskis is pointing out is that the term "nonstandard" is misleading.

Comment: @Mikhail: cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal --- as well, I don't think that by "infinitesimal calculus" most people mean non-rigorous Euler-style computations.  Call it "Transfer principle-based infinitesimal calculus" if  you must.

Comment: @Dima, Euler's computations are far more rigorous than they are reputed to be.  See for example this text: http://www.ams.org/notices/201408/rnoti-p848.pdf

Comment: @Mikhail : don't you need some NSA to make proper sense of Euler's derivation of the infinite product formula for $\sin x$ ?

Comment: @Dima, that's precisely the point. When it comes to interpreting the procedures found in Euler, modern Weierstrassian frameworks are less suitable than modern infinitesimal frameworks, be it Robinson's, Lawvere's, or Bell's. Mostly scholars have been trying to understand Euler from the viewpoint of Weierstrassian frameworks, hence the routine claims of "non-rigorous" and even "dismal" as J. Gray put it. The source of the disdain for Euler lies in the inappropriateness of conceptual frameworks being applied to interpret his procedures.

Comment: @Mikhail : I always found it very tricky to apply the transfer principle in the setting of real algebraic geometry - IMHO it's easier in the setting of univariate calculus... Well, I am no Euler, and I very often got lost.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik, I am not familiar with the literature using a hyperreal framework to do real algebraic geometry. What are you referring to exactly?

Comment: @Mikhail, it's a common place in real algebraic geometry to work over the field of Puiseux series in an infinitesimal $\epsilon$ over $\mathbb{R}$ (or other real closed fields). Cf. e.g. http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted2.html

Comment: @Dima, it has been my impression that in the context of algebraic geometry one doesn't need hyperreal infinitesimals and Grothendieck-style nilpotent infinitesimals are sufficient.  Is this correct in the context of real algebraic geometry?

Comment: @Mikhail, it could be enough for our purposes, although I never heard about nilpotent infinitesimals. References?

Comment: @Dima, here is what I found at wiki: "His foundational work on algebraic geometry is at a higher level of abstraction than all prior versions. He adapted the use of non-closed generic points, which led to the theory of schemes. He also pioneered the systematic use of nilpotents. As 'functions' these can take only the value 0, but they carry infinitesimal information, in purely algebraic settings."

Comment: @Mikhail, this looks way too general for the purpose of "smoothing out" real algebraic and semialgebraic sets. In the computable constructions there one anyway uses only $\epsilon^{p/q}$ for bounded $|p/q|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned University of Hawaii --

[David Ross](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ross/) regularly teaches nonstandard analysis and infinitesimal calculus at University of Hawaii in various forms, for instance

- [MATH 649K](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ross/649.htm) (a regular grad course), Spring 2008
- [MATH 699](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ross/699.htm) (reading course), Spring 2011

We also usually cover the topic in our senior-level course on mathematical logic (MATH 455), although I suppose a lot of universities do that.

**But** infinitesimal calculus is not part of our standard calculus syllabus.

Answer (score 2):

So far I have been able to find out that true infinitesimal calculus was taught at the following universities:

University of Hawaii;

University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign;

University of Iowa;

University of Wisconsin at Madison.

Anyone who has either taught or studied in such courses there is requested to share his or her experiences.

Comment: http://news.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=99232&cid=8500301

Comment: Thanks, @BenCrowell. I found the following comment there: "I find it disheartening that the book was allowed to go out of print, and that there are now no (as far as I'm aware) current popular calculus texts using the infinitesimal-based approach. I, like the original poster, and like most students learning today, was always confused by what you could and couldn't do with dy and dx. How I wish I'd had this book 20 years ago." It is nice to see such enthusiasm about Keisler's book but one correction: the book is currently in print at Dover. Furthermore, there are today numerous TIC textbooks.